# Hot Towel (HotTowellete) as DotNetNuke module

Tags: dotnetnuke, hottowel

Has anybody ever tried to create a DNN module with HotTowel (or Hotowellete)? I created a module but instantly got errors about virtual directories and such, but I think it is just the tip of the ice.

Any ideas will be welcomed.

thanks,
David

Comment: please show us your code that you tried and error in browser